# Actionscript: ExternalInterface.addCallback is not working in IE

Tags: actionscript-3

Html:

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="100%" height="100%" id="testqwe">
    <param name="movie" value="http://www.mydomain.com/swf/testqwe.swf" />
    <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
    <embed name="testqwe" src="http://www.mydomain.com/swf/testqwe.swf" width="100%" height="100%" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
</object>
```

Javascript:

```
try {
    if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE') != '-1') {
        var embed = jQuery('#testqwe')[0];
    }
    else {
        var embed = jQuery('#testqwe embed')[0];
    }
}
catch(e)
{
    log({error:e});
}
```

Actionscript:

```
private function jsAPI():void{
    ExternalInterface.addCallback("callfromjs",callfromjs);
}
private function callfromjs(js:Object):void{
 //code here
}
```

When i'm trying to call embed.callfromjs() it says that Object doesn't support this property or method.

What i'm doing wrong? I think the problem is in html markup.Something missing probably or i made a mistake somewhere.

It's working in Firefox/Chrome/Opera, but doesn't in all IE.

Help! Spent around 4-5 hours and nothing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you verify that the proper block in the `if` is getting called from IE?

Have you tried using [SWFObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) to load the SWF?  Persoanlly, I always use the dynamic method to add things to the page.  This will eliminate the need for the browser sniffing.  SWFObject also has an [API](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/api), and there is a call to get the flash app by id if you really need to use static publishing.

BTW, even though it is now deprecated, take a look at [jQuery.browser](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/) instead of parsing the UA string yourself.  The SWFObject API also has a UA parser and some flags that you can use.

Comment: Yea i have stopped at that library. It worth it's wight :)

Answer (score 2):

Try adding an id attribute to your embed tag,and a name attribute to your object tag. I have this issue before, and it seems to me the fix was something like this.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using jquery so I use the plugins because they are significantly easier.

I had to switch from jquery.flash plugin to the jquery.SWFObject plugin. because the jquery.flash plugin doesn't work at all and gives the same error when refreshing or navigating away from the page.

**Now I'm using the SWFObject jquery plugin, and changed the internal callback name from "stop" (a reserved word) to "kill" and everything started to work fine. Seems to have solved the problems.**

Firefox seems to work fine and overwrites the function, IE broke (no surprise there.)

IE gave me the following error:
"Object doesn't support this property or method" line 48 char 3

I wrote to Luke (the author) about the problem with the jquery.flash plugin. I think he is not using both wrappers which may be the cause of the failure, dunno for sure. IE FAIL.

fwiw, when i used the jquery.flash plugin IE was giving me the same error when I left/navigated away from the page.

"Object doesn't support this property or method" line 53 char 3.

- [jQuery Flash Plugin](http://jquery.lukelutman.com/plugins/flash/)
- [jQuery SWFObject Plugin](http://jquery.thewikies.com/swfobject/)

*note: a subtle difference between the plugins one uses "src" and the other uses "swf" to declare the SWF path.*

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var getFlash = function(name) {
       if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1) {
           return window[name];
       } else {
           return document[name];
       }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to add to Shanimal's post above: we've discovered that IE8 in particular has several keywords that one cannot add via flash's ExternalInterface.addCallback. Adding these keywords will result in an

"Object doesn't support this property or method  JScript - script block, line 48 character 3"

error when the first one is called. What is slightly confusing is that all your other methods will be fine and the external interface will carry on functioning providing you don't call methods with these keywords.

List of keywords identified so far: stop, zoom, pan.

IE9 and other browsers seem fine.  If you are getting this error try renaming your callbacks. Isn't IE8 lovely? ;-)